# Multiplying Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to multiply two arrays, of the same length and create a third array from it.

I've tried loops and I think a nested loop would be the way forward.

Below is my attempt, that multiplied out the whole array

```
var one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var two = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//var partOne = one.length

var partOne = []
  for(var i=0; i<one.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<two.length;j++) {
      partOne.push({value:one[i] * two[i]});
    }
  }
```

Looking for something similar to the below;

```
var a = [3, 5]
var b = [5, 5]

//answer

var c = [15, 25]
```

Comment: Please include what you've tried with nested loops

Comment: You don't need nested loops, just a single loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function multiply(a, b) {
    var c = [];
    for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        c.push(a[i]*b[i]);
    }
    return c;
}
var a = [3, 5 ];
var b = [5, 5 ];
var c = multiply(a, b);
console.log(c);
```

```js
var a = [3, 5 ]
var b = [5, 5 ]
var c = []

for (var i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
    c.push(a[i]*b[i]);
}

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = [3, 5];
let b = [5, 5];

// x is each element from a
// i is index of a
let c = a.map((x, i) => { return x * b[i]; });
```

returns

```
// Array [ 15, 25 ]
```

Comment: I suggest using a different variable for the parameter than the original array, so you don't confuse readers.